# Publish a File and Other Values

Tags: solidity, react

***Background***

I'm working on this app that allows users to upload PDF files to IPFS. A `Document` consists of the title, address (the uploader), price, description, and the file itself.

[image: Browser]

I've looked at other similar questions but none that I found solved my problem.

***Problem***

Whenever I fill out the information (as shown in the screenshot below), I always encounter this error that occurs in the `onSubmit` function.

`Uncaught Error: invalid string value (arg="file", coderType="string", value=[{"path":"QmUqB9dWDCeZ5nth9YKRJTQ6PcnfrGPPx1vzdyNWV6rh8s","hash":"QmUqB9dWDCeZ5nth9YKRJTQ6PcnfrGPPx1vzdyNWV6rh8s","size":60035}]) at Object.n [as throwError] (web3.min.js:21199)`

***Code***

*App.jsx*

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import MyContract from "./contracts/MyContract.json";
import Web3 from "web3";
import web3 from "./web3";
import ipfs from "./ipfs";
import storehash from "./storehash";

import "./styles/App.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      myContractHash: null,
      buffer: "",
      ethAddress: "",
      account: null
    };
  }

  async loadWeb3() {
    if (window.ethereum) {
      window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
      await window.ethereum.enable();
    } else if (window.web3) {
      window.web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
      window.alert("Please switch to a browser that has an Ethereum wallet, such as MetaMask.");
    }
  }

  async loadBlockchain() {
    const web3 = window.web3;
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    this.setState({ account: accounts[0] });

    const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
    const networkData = MyContract.networks[networkId];

    if (networkData) {
      const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(MyContract.abi, networkData.address);
      this.setState({ contract });

      const myContractHash = await contract.methods.getHash().call();
      this.setState({ myContractHash });
    }
  }

  async componentWillMount() {
    await this.loadWeb3();
    await this.loadBlockchain();
  }
   
  captureFile = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    const file = event.target.files[0];

    let reader = new window.FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    reader.onloadend = () => this.convertToBuffer(reader);
  };

  convertToBuffer = async (reader) => {
    // Convert file to buffer so that it can be uploaded to IPFS
    const buffer = await Buffer.from(reader.result);
    this.setState({buffer});
  };

  onSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Take the user's MetaMask address
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    console.log("Sending from MetaMask account: " + accounts[0]);

    // To use the contract's methods
    this.MyContract = new web3.eth.Contract(
      MyContract.abi,
      MyContract.address
    );
    this.MyContract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);

    // Retrieve the contract address from storehash.js
    const ethAddress= await storehash.options.address;
    this.setState({ethAddress});
    
    // Save document to IPFS, return its hash, and set it to state
    await ipfs.add(this.state.buffer, (err, myContractHash) => {
      console.log(err, myContractHash);
      this.setState({ myContractHash: myContractHash[0].hash });

      this.MyContract.methods
        .publishDocument(
          document.getElementById("title").value,
          document.getElementById("price").value,
          document.getElementById("description").value,
          myContractHash
        )
        .send({ from: this.account, gas: 5000000 });

      console.log("Success!");
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="header">
          <a href="/">
            <img src={require("./media/logo.png")} className="logo" />
          </a>
          <div className="header-text">
            <span className="address">{this.state.account}</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="text-wrapper">
          <p className="heading">Publish a Document</p>
          <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            <p>Title</p>
            <input type="text" id="title" className="form-input" placeholder="Write title..." />
            <br />
            <p>Price</p>
            <input type="number" id="price" className="form-input" placeholder="0" />
            <br />
            <p>Description</p>
            <input type="textarea" id="description" className="form-input" placeholder="Write description..." />
            <br />
            <p>Choose a document to upload</p>
            <input type="file" onChange={this.captureFile} className="input-file" />

            <button type="submit">Publish</button>
          </form>
        </div>

        <div className="text-wrapper">
          <p className="heading">Feed</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      // <a href={`https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/${this.state.myContractHash}`}>Click to download the file</a>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

*MyContract.sol*

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.5.16 <0.7.0;

contract MyContract {
  struct Document {
    string title;
    address payable uploader;
    uint256 price;
    string description;
    string file;
  }

  string myContractHash;

  Document[] public documents;

  mapping(address => uint256[]) public filesUploaded;
  mapping(address => uint256[]) public documentsPublished;
  mapping(address => uint256[]) public documentsPurchased;

  // Setters
  function setHash(string memory ipfsHash) public {
    myContractHash = ipfsHash;
  }

  // Getters
  function getHash() public view returns (string memory ipfsHash) {
    return myContractHash;
  }

  function getDocument(uint256 i) public view returns (Document memory) {
    return documents[i];
  }

  function getDocumentsPublishedTotal(address user) public view returns (uint256) {
    return documentsPublished[user].length;
  }

  function getDocumentsPublished(address user, uint256 i) public view returns (uint256) {
    return documentsPublished[user][i];
  }

  function getDocumentsPurchasedTotal(address user) public view returns (uint256) {
    return documentsPurchased[user].length;
  }

  function getDocumentsPurchased(address user, uint256 i) public view returns (uint256) {
    return documentsPurchased[user][i];
  }

  function publishDocument(
    string memory title,
    uint256 price,
    string memory description,
    string memory file
  ) public {
    require(bytes(title).length > 0 && bytes(title).length < 20, "Invalid title length");
    require(bytes(description).length > 0 && bytes(description).length < 10000, "Invalid description length");

    documents.push(Document(title, msg.sender, price, description, file));
    documentsPublished[msg.sender].push(documents.length);
  }

  function isDocumentPurchased(uint256 i) public view returns (bool) {
    for (uint256 j = 0; j < documentsPurchased[msg.sender].length; j++) {
      if (documentsPurchased[msg.sender][j] == i) return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  function purchaseDocument(uint256 i) setPause public payable {
    require(msg.sender != documents[i].uploader && !isDocumentPurchased(i));

    require(msg.value == documents[i].price, "Invalid price");

    documents[i].uploader.transfer(msg.value);

    documentsPurchased[msg.sender].push(i);
  }
}
```

How do I solve this? Thank you for your help!

Comment: The message tells you that you are passing input parameter `file` to contract function `publishDocument` as a JSON object instead of as a string.

Comment: And BTW, please replace it from a screenshot to plaintext.

Comment: @goodvibration I've edited!

Comment: Great, do you understand the problem?

Comment: @goodvibration yes, but I'm not sure how to get it as a string.

Comment: How about sending `JSON.stringify(myContractHash)` instead of `myContractHash`?

Comment: @goodvibration I've just tried that and got a different error: `Error: This contract object doesn't have address set yet, please set an address first.`

Comment: That's a different problem.

Comment: `MyContract = new web3.eth.Contract(...)` is not nearly enough. It is a local object representing your contract, but you still need to actually get that contract deployed on the network. Start by sending a deployment transaction ([here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#deploy) is how).

Comment: @goodvibration I've deployed it to Rinkeby using `trufle migrate --network rinkeby`. I'm still not quite sure how to deploy it to web3 though; does this tutorial I found achieve it? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eyETb2Ib2pk

Comment: See the link in my previous comment.

Comment: @goodvibration is the code supposed to be in the `index.js` file? I'm a bit confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Uncaught Error: invalid string value (arg="file", coderType="string", value=[{"path":"QmUqB9dWDCeZ5nth9YKRJTQ6PcnfrGPPx1vzdyNWV6rh8s","hash":"QmUqB9dWDCeZ5nth9YKRJTQ6PcnfrGPPx1vzdyNWV6rh8s","size":60035}]) at Object.n [as throwError] (web3.min.js:21199)

This error-message tells you that you are not passing the input argument `file` as a `string`.

And `[{"path":"...","hash":"...","size":60035}]` is indeed not a string, but an array of objects.

You may want to pass `JSON.stringify(x)` instead of `x` for this input argument.